# Exclude some files when doing grep

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I want to search an expression say "abcd" in all files of a directory but exclude some file of a certain type in my search

like

```
grep -rn 'abcd' *
```

But the result should not include expression found in files with extensions .js and .h. How will I do that?

Comment: If you need grep-only solution, then you could add -H (which will show filename to each occurrence) and pipe it through another grep. you would have something like `grep -rnH 'abcd' * | grep -v '\.js:'`, which will exclude .js files. Otherwise, find / awk as suggested bellow

Answer (score 2):

use the `--exclude` option

`grep 'your string here' -r --exclude=\*.{js,h}`

Answer (score 1):

So, at this point I typically advise to use `ack`, which is like `grep`, but has a lot of built-in features like file type selection.

But with grep, and a bit of shell magic, this can work:

```
find -not -iname '*.h' -not -iname '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -rn 'abcd'
```